# KeyboardEvent.shiftKey v/s KeyboardEvent.Key === 'Shift' , when e.Key === 'Shift' can e.shiftKey be False simultaneously

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, user-interface, keyboard-events

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapElement, 'keyup', (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
                if (e.ctrlKey) {
                    this.singleSelectModeOn = false;
                } else if (e.shiftKey || e.Key === 'Shift') {
                    this.shiftKeyPressed = false;
                }
            });
```

ran into this issue while catching KeyUp event on a map component when listening on the keyUP event in F12 source debugger watch - found e.shiftKey = false while e.Key === 'Shift'.

I am confused why that behavior exists ?

+attched F12 watch details

[image]

Comment: If you hit other key by holding shift, that boolean will be true

Comment: may be I dint understand what you stated completely but the problem here is not making it a false true - why in the first place there is an ambiguity between these two event captures ? how is the key selected Shift and e.shiftKey a false

Comment: The same as with Ctrl. You can hold it clicked and click other key. But I think you might have an XY problem. Might help if you provide more details on what the final goal is

Comment: in my goal, I was trying to select a rectangular portion of the map by pressing shift and simultaneously using mouse drag event

Comment: - Actually I understand my mistake now thanks @JuliusDzidzevičius

in the KeuUp event trigger
I cant use e.shiftkey bcz I just released it and its not true
I should use e.key === 'Shift' bcz thats the key I interacted with most recently

Comment: I found this too for `onkeydown`. Firefox does not set `shiftKey: true`, except, it does when I test directly. But in React, I'm getting `key: Shift, shiftKey: true` always, and in Firefox with React, I'm getting `key: Shift, shiftKey: false`.

Unsure if this is React or Firefox' bug. Very irritating anyway. :)